# Reduce a LambdaExpression Signature

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I couldn't think of a better way to word the question, but what I'm trying to do is reduce the signature of a LambdaExpression from `Expression<Func<MyObject, FilterObject, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<MyObject, bool>>` by handling the instance of the `FilterObject` before the LambdaExpression is evaluated.

Here's a quick example:

```
AddFilter("Filter Name", FilterTypes.All,
    (x, y) => GetConjunctionResult(
        x.PersonA.IsSomething, x.PersonB.IsSomething, y.ConjunctionType));

private static bool GetConjunctionResult(bool personA, bool personB,
    ConjunctionType conjunctionType)
{
    switch (conjunctionType)
    {
        case ConjunctionType.Both:
            return personA && personB:
        case ConjunctionType.Either:
            return personA && personB;
        case ConjunctionType.PersonA:
            return personA;
        case ConjunctionType.PersonB:
            return personB;
        case ConjunctionType.Neither:
            return !personA && !personB;
    }
}
```

So I want this overload of `AddFilter` to create an object of type `FilterObject` and embed it into a LambdaExpression along the lines of:

```
var filter = new FilterObject();
// create Expression<Func<MyObject, bool>> lambda = x => GetConjunctionResult(
//     x.PersonA.IsSomething, x.PersonB.IsSomething, filter.ConjunctionType));
```

Now there might be a better way to do this, so I'm open to any suggestions that eschew this approach altogether.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to mix runtime with expressions. Since most Linq Providers are not Turing Complete, this CANNOT work. Why don't you just pass in a BinaryExpression of the right type as y? For example. Instead of passing in an Enum of Both, pass in `Expression.And`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
var filter = new FilterObject()
```

it should be:

```
Expression<Func<MyObject, bool>> exp2 = 
             Expression.Lambda<Func<MyObject, bool>>(
                        Expression.Invoke(myExp, 
                                          myExp.Parameters[0], 
                                          Expression.Constant(filter)),
                        myExp.Parameters[0]);
```

`Expression.Invoke` will call the other expression and pass as the first parameter the first parameter of the new expression, and as the second parameter an `Expression.Constant` with your filter.

Are you trying to use Currying with Expression trees?

Comment: From someone who's understanding of currying comes from what he just read 5 minutes prior, I'd say yes, that seems to be what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help xanatos. That was exactly what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach than calling `Invoke` is to substitute the parameter in the Expression tree directly using a `ExpressionVisitor`. You can define a couple of simple extension methods to make this easy. In this case they can apply the first parameter of the expression (you'd need to change your signature or adapt them to apply a middle parameter).

Usage:

```
      var applied = expr.Apply(constValueForFirstParameter);
```

In a static class define these extension methods:

```
public static Expression<Func<U, V, bool>> Apply<T, U, V>(this Expression<Func<T, U, V, bool>> input, T value)
{
    var swap = new ExpressionSubstitute(input.Parameters[0], Expression.Constant(value));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<U, V, bool>>(swap.Visit(input.Body), input.Parameters[1], input.Parameters[2]);
    return lambda;
}

public static Expression<Func<U, bool>> Apply<T, U>(this Expression<Func<T, U, bool>> input, T value)
{
    var swap = new ExpressionSubstitute(input.Parameters[0], Expression.Constant(value));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<U, bool>>(swap.Visit(input.Body), input.Parameters[1]);
    return lambda;
}

class ExpressionSubstitute : System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ExpressionSubstitute(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (node == from) return to;
        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't what "currying" means.  This is partial application.  Currying a `Func<A, B, R>` is turning it into a `Func<A, Func<B, R>>`, not a `Func<A, R>`.